# Getting create statement of a table in a linked server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

Using SQL Server 2019.

I have a Linked Server and I can see the database in it and all the tables.  I need to get the create statement for one of the tables, but right clicking `Script Table As->CREATE To`, the `CREATE To` option is greyed out, only the `SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE to` options are available to me.

Is there some way I can make this not greyed out or some other way to get the create to statement from this table?

Comment: You need to have the `VIEW DEFINITION` permission granted to you on the database. I.e. `GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO <user>`.

Comment: If you want the whole database scripted, then right click the database and select Tasks--> Generate Scripts... and then follow the wizard